# Specify separate icon and name for each instance of an app?

Tags: terminal, bash, dock

For example, if I have a command line program (say nano) I want to launch directly with a shortcut, but I want the new instance of Terminal.app to have a dock icon depicting nano running in a terminal window, and for it to be named "Nano" in the dock. I also need this to be done without creating a second copy of the Terminal.app file, and preferably for it to be compatible with the command `open -n -a Terminal.app /path/to/binary`

Comment: You said "and preferably for it to be compatible with the command `open -n -a Terminal.app /bin/bash/nano`" and that command returns "The file /bin/bash/nano does not exist."

Comment: @user3439894 that was a typo, I had meant to type the location of the nano binary and accidently appended it to the Bash path. Just assume for the sake of the hypothetical that the file does exist, because I was only using nano as an example anyway and would be using it with my own command line program in practice. When I said "*compatible*" I meant it needed to be usable in conjunction with the solution.